# Is there a non-trivial function satisfying $\int_0^1 (f(x)+x)^a \, dx=0$ for $a$ a positive real (or integer)?

Tags: functional-equations, integral-equations

Here is the functional equation:

$$\int_0^1 (f(x)+x)^a \, dx=0$$

Is there a function $f(x)$ that satisfies it for any $a>0$ and $f(x)\not\equiv-x$?

What about the case where $a$ is an integer?

Comment: When you say "any $a > 0$" do you mean "all $a > 0$"?  If $a$ is an even integer, your equation says $f(x) + x = 0$ for almost every $x$ (with respect to Lebesgue measure).

Comment: It depends on the conditions you have on the regularity of $f$. When a=2 or any other even integer, the function $(f(x) + x)^2$ is non-negative. If $f$ is continuous, this can only happen if $f(x) + x = 0$. In general,  we must have $f(x) + x = 0$ almost everywhere (like in Almeida's example).

Comment: Why not define $g(x)=f(x)+x $ and ask about $g(x)^a$? It looks like you just chose an abstruse form of this.

Comment: @LucasKaufmann we can assume $f(x)$ to be non-real.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be an finite set such that $S \subset [0,1]$, and $M$ an subset with the same ammount of elements of $S$, such that $M \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Now let $\begin{cases} f(x) = -x \text{ if } x\notin S \\
f(x) = g(x) \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$
Where $g(x)$ is some abritary function $g:S \to M$

Then the integral in question can be computed by splitting it into an finite sum of other integrals, in which $f(x)$ behaves exactly as $f(x)=-x$.

Now, It's fully possible this trickery I did is forbidden by the $f(x) \not\equiv -x$, i don't actually know how restrcitve that notation is. Please do let me know